# Get sub total of two column for particular criterion and another total as full group by X parameter

Tags: mysql

I want to group by keyword name, get sum of cf1+cf2 (where bug_status=CLOSED or RESOLVED) and get total sum (irrespective of bug status). Output will have 3 columns like mentioned.

## Tried query but no luck:

```
SELECT keyworddefs.name as keyword, IFNULL(SUM(bugs.cf1 +  bugs.cf2),0) as completed, (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bugs.cf1 +  bugs.cf2) ,0) FROM bugs, keywords, keyworddefs WHERE (keywords.bug_id = bugs .bug_id) AND (keyworddefs.id=keywords.keywordid) AND (keyworddefs.name LIKE 'K%')) as total FROM bugs, keywords, keyworddefs WHERE (keywords.bug_id = bugs .bug_id) AND (keyworddefs.id=keywords.keywordid) AND (bugs.bug_status  = 'VERIFIED' OR bugs.bug_status  = 'CLOSED') GROUP BY keyworddefs.name DESC;
```

Here's the query formatted.

```
SELECT keyworddefs.name as keyword,
       IFNULL(SUM(bugs.cf1 +  bugs.cf2),0) as completed,
       (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(bugs.cf1 +  bugs.cf2) ,0) 
          FROM bugs, keywords, keyworddefs
         WHERE (keywords.bug_id = bugs .bug_id)
           AND (keyworddefs.id=keywords.keywordid)
           AND (keyworddefs.name LIKE 'K%')) as total
  FROM bugs, keywords, keyworddefs
 WHERE (keywords.bug_id = bugs .bug_id)
   AND (keyworddefs.id=keywords.keywordid)
   AND (bugs.bug_status  = 'VERIFIED' OR bugs.bug_status  = 'CLOSED')
 GROUP BY keyworddefs.name DESC;
```

## SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a11b4/7

## Expected:

```
Matching records:
cf1+cf2    bugid, keyword     bug_status
5          (102, 'K1')        CLOSED
3          (565, 'K2')        CLOSED
3          (1352, 'K1')       VERIFIED
4          (13634, 'K1')      NEW

# Query output should be:
keyword     completed    total
K1          8            12
K2          3            3
```

DDLs:

## bugs table1 (master table) :

```
CREATE TABLE `bugs` (
     `bug_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `bug_date` date NOT NULL,
     `cf1` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `cf2` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `bug_status` varchar(200) NOT NULL)
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `bugs` (`bug_id`, `bug_date`, `cf1`, `cf2`, `bug_status`) VALUES 
     (102,   '2016-07-19', 2, 1, 'CLOSED'), 
     (72123, '2016-07-19', 2, 1, 'VERIFIED'),
     (57234, '2016-07-19', 2, 1, 'VERIFIED'),
     (1352,  '2016-07-19', 2, 1, 'VERIFIED'),
     (565,   '2016-07-19', 2, 1, 'CLOSED'),
     (13634, '2016-07-22', 2, 2, 'NEW');
```

## keywords table2 (having keyword ids):

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords` (
   `bug_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `keywordid` varchar(11) NOT NULL)
  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `keywords` (`bug_id`, `keywordid`) VALUES 
   (102, '3'), 
   (565, '4'), 
   (398, '1'), 
   (565, '2'), 
   (1352, '1'), 
   (57234, '2'), 
   (1363, '1'), 
   (72123, '2'), 
   (13634, '3');
```

## keyworddefs table3 (having keyword names according to keywordid):

```
CREATE TABLE `keyworddefs` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL) 
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `keyworddefs` (`id`, `name`, `description`) VALUES 
     (1, 'J1', 'My J1 item'),
     (2, 'J2', 'My J2 item'),
     (3, 'K1', 'My K1 item'),
     (4, 'K2', 'My K2 item');
```

How can I get output like expected?

Comment: It's helpful both to people who look at your code, and to you, to format your queries rather than dumping them into single lines.

Comment: Right, thanks Ollie! Will take care next time, sorry it is big post so missed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're making this too complicated.

For one thing, you should join your `keywords` and `keyworddefs` tables `ON keywords.keywordid = keyworddefs.name`. You're using `keyworddefs.id`. That's a number. So, your old-timey early 1990s comma join yields no results.

For another thing, you don't need to join the `keyworddefs` table to get your result.

`SUM()` operations rarely yield `NULL` results. So, you should put your conditionals inside the parentheses of `SUM()` rather than outside.

Finally, you need a `GROUP BY` operation with two `SUM()` aggregates in it. One should be conditioned on the `bug_status` and the other should not.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a11b4/11/0

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT keywords.keywordid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN bugs.bug_status IN ('CLOSED', 'RESOLVED')
                THEN bugs.cf1 + bugs.cf2
                ELSE 0 END)                                   completed,
       SUM(bugs.cf1 + bugs.cf2)                               total
  FROM bugs
  JOIN keywords ON bugs.bug_id = keywords.bug_id
 GROUP BY keywords.keywordid
 ORDER BY keywords.keywordid
```

If you need to filter your results by `keywords.keywordid LIKE 'K%'`, you can just add a where clause.

Comment: Thank you very much Ollie! Your answer is so helpful but i made a mistake when copying data for e.g. keywords doesn't contain direct name of keyword but id of keyworddefs's id. Updated keywords table, can you please help me accordingly? Updated your fiddle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Extended query from Ollie's comment, it works fine with couple of changes.

Highly appreciated Ollie!

```
SELECT keyworddefs.name, 
SUM(CASE WHEN bugs.bug_status IN ('CLOSED', 'VERIFIED') THEN bugs.cf1 + bugs.cf2 ELSE 0 END) completed,
SUM(bugs.cf1 + bugs.cf2) total
FROM bugs
JOIN keywords ON bugs.bug_id = keywords.bug_id
JOIN keyworddefs ON keyworddefs.id = keywords.keywordid
WHERE keyworddefs.name LIKE 'K%' 
GROUP BY keywords.keywordid
ORDER BY keyworddefs.name DESC;
```